# 101 Switching Protocols

Tags: rest, api

I am reading rest http status and I came across this 101 status code.
Can anyone tell me, what is Switching Protocols and in which case the server should respond with 101 http code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This response code is returned if the previous request contained a request to upgrade a currently used connection to an other protocol via the usage of a `Connection: upgrade` and [`Upgrade` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.7), that defines one or multiple other protocols to change to.

This feature is useful if you are not sure whether a server supports HTTP/2 yet and you start connecting to it via HTTP/1.1 first and once you learned that it also supports HTTP/2 switch to that protocol on requesting the server to upgrade the current connection to HTTP/2. A server can advertise the support of other protocols on adding an `Upgrade` header with the supported protocols to its responses.

As stated in the RFC a client will issue a request such as:

```
GET /some/resource HTTP/1.1
Host: www.acme.com
Connection: upgrade
Upgrade: HTTP/2.0
```

If the server supports HTTP/2 it will probably reply with a response such as

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Connection: upgrade
Upgrade: HTTP/2.0
```

to indicate that the connection was successfully upgraded to HTTP/2 and any further communication over this connection should follow the HTTP/2 protocol.

Note, however, that a server is not forced to switch protocols. It may also ignore such a request completely if it prefers to communicate via the old protocol. While the list of suggested protocols should be expressed in the order of preference, with the most preferred protocol first, a server is further allowed to ignore any preference order and select one of the suggested protocols on its own. However, the server is not allowed to switch to any other protocol not indicated by the client as a client might not support that kind of protocol and thus prevent further communication.